# whether the update of Pod description information can ensure global consistency?

Tags: kubernetes

In k8s, users can modify pod description information or meta through http api.
In the case of high concurrency, whether the update of Pod description information can ensure global consistency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the information including the pod metadata is stored in [etcd](https://etcd.io). etcd is a strongly consistent, distributed key-value store that provides a reliable way to store data. So that means you are supposed to have strong consistency.